# Xcode: use old build system from command line

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild, podspec

I need access to the xcodebuild tools because I need it in podspec, because the lint to uses the command line but I get multiple errors about Swift-compatibility headers.

Comment: can you give us more info what you are doing and what are the errors?

Comment: I am working on a pod repo push command.

Comment: Add `-UseModernBuildSystem=NO`